# iOS 13 NSNumberFormatter currency decimal

Tags: objective-c, ios13, nsnumberformatter

it seems like in iOS 13 it has changed the NSNumberFormatter way of displaying figures. 
Previously in iOS 12, setting the region format to Colombia, for a figure of 12.00, it will be shown as 12 which is correct.
However now in iOS 13, it shows as 12,00 which is not correct as in Colombia it should not show the ,00 at the back of the 12. 
Any idea what has changed in iOS 13 and how we can workaround for this?

Here's my code. Thanks!

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[formatter setCurrencySymbol:@""]; 
NSString *floatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", floatValue];
NSDecimalNumber* number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:floatString];
NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
NSLog(@"%@", numberString");
```

Update: After updating to iOS 13.2, this issue is gone.

Comment: I put your code into a simple Objective-C project and ran it under iOS 13.2 and I get a simple `12` for the output. I set the formatter's locale to `es_CO` to simulate being in Colombia.

Comment: However in iOS12, there is no need to set the formatter's locale to es_CO, it should be automatic.

Comment: I need to set the locale to es_CO for the test because that's not my default locale.

Comment: Understand that, but the purpose of this code is that everyone should see their currency in their own format based on their iPad region's setting. If we have to set the locale manually, then it defeats the purpose.

Comment: It seems like an issue to do with iOS 13.1, after updating to 13.2 the issue is gone. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 13.1 has a bug when you have a different decimal point instead of . to anything else.

For example: My locale is Poland. So if I have amountString = "4.5". Following code return always nil.

```
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.currencySymbol = ""
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
currencyFormatter.locale = Locale.current
if let finalNumber = currencyFormatter.number(from: amountString){
    return finalNumber.doubleValue
}
return nil
```